# Behaviour for Python-For loop with conditional increment (gives wrong output)

Tags: python, for-loop

I want a for loop that increments based on certain conditions. Here are the conditions:

The first input array contains the correct answers to an exam, like ["a", "a", "b", "d"]. The second one is "answers" array and contains student's answers.

The two arrays are not empty and are the same length. Return the score for this array of answers, giving +4 for each correct answer, -1 for each incorrect answer, and +0 for each blank answer(empty string).

```
def check_exam(arr1,arr2):
    counter=0
    for i in arr1:
        for j in arr2:
            if i==j:
                counter+=4
            elif i!=j:
                     counter+=1
            elif i== " ":
                    counter=0
    return counter
```

If every answer is correct like:

`print(check_exam(["a", "a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a", "a"]))` it returns 64.

If two answers are wrong like:

`print(check_exam(["a", "a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "a", "a"]))`it returns 24.

Comment: What you want to do is to loop over `arr1` and `arr2` at the same time, but what you have implemented is looping over `arr2` for each item of `arr1`.

Comment: Imo you don't want a nested loop, but to compare the first element of each array with each other, then the two elements with index 1, then the two with index 2..... Have a look at python's [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej Jenny Two things
One try and specify the problem a bit better, what I found was that your total marks where too high as it was counting in both loops. Next time try and give the expected marks as well.
To solve it I made the loops loop through a range and only compare the answers of each index with each other. For example, now answer 1 in correct answers is only compared to answer 1 in student answers.

Hope this helps.

```
def check_exam(correct_answers, student_answers):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, len(correct_answers)):
        for j in range(0, len(student_answers)):
            if i == j:
                if correct_answers[i] == student_answers[j]:
                    counter += 4
                elif correct_answers[i] != student_answers[j]:
                    counter -= 1
            elif i == " ":
                pass
    return counter


print(check_exam(["a", "a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a", "a"]))

print(check_exam(["a", "a", "a", "a"], ["b", "a", "a", "a"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating both lists at the same time - you can do this most easily like this

```
for solution, answer in zip(arr1, arr2):
```

You are not counting correctly, every time you have an empty string, you return -1 instead of 0.
You need to check for the empty string first - in python thats most easily done with

```
if not j: // i think you need to check for j here, based on your description.
  counter += 0
  continue // forces the next loop
```

and then your if /else construct,.

Depending on your class, I would probably skip the loop alotger and use map and sum here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `zip` to iterate over two arrays at the same time.

Add 4 to the score if matches else if student answer is blank, don't do anything in that iteration else `-1` from the score.

```
# assuming arr1 as correct answer and arr2 as student answer
>>> def check_exam(arr1,arr2):
    score = 0
    for ca, sa in zip(arr1, arr2): #ca = correct answer, sa = student answer
        if ca == sa:
            score+=4
        elif sa == '': # or elif not sa:
            continue
        else:
            score-=1
    return score

>>> print(check_exam(["a", "a", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "a", "a"]))
16
>>> print(check_exam(["a", "a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "a", "a"]))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement nested loop this case so you can try this:

```py
def check_exam(correct_answers, student_answers):
    return sum(list(map(lambda x, y: 4 if x==y else -1 if x!=y else 0 , correct_answers, student_answers)))
```